# Linux Bash. Send mailx from inside a while loop that reads lines of a file

Tags: linux, bash, mailx, ifs

In a Linux bash script, I am trying to send out 1 email using mailx for each line of a file that I read. The line read contains the parameters to build the email. I can send an identical email outside of this loop. Thanks for any input.

```
#!/bin/bash
in_email_file='./in_file.txt'
email_adr="address@somewhere.com"

while IFS='|' read -r subject body email
do
    #these are echoed
    echo "$subject"
    echo "$body"
    echo "$email"

 #this does not get sent
 echo "$body" | mailx -s "$subject" -r $email_adr $email    

done < $in_email_file

#this gets sent
echo "Email body sent from outside loop" | mailx -s "Email subject sent from 
outside loop" -r $email_adr $email_adr
```

The input file being read looks like this:

```
subject1|body1|address@domain.com
subject2|body2|address@domain.com
subject3|body3|address@domain.com
```

Comment: You have to show the contents of the input file and what you do inside of the loop.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the exact code you're trying to run inside the loop, but regardless I suspect this is an [occurrence of a common](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) (frustrating) stumbling block with bash scripting. Likely, you're trying to do something/anything interesting inside a `read` loop (ie: recipe for pitfall).

**tl;dr** Here's how to avoid `read`s inside `read`s:

```
mapfile -t lines < "$in_email_file" # affectively one of the reads
for line in "${lines}";do #now no read occurs here
  IFS=\| read subject body email < <(echo "$line")

  # ... mailx thing you're doing
done
```

To summarize: use the built-in `mapfile` so you can write a normal `for` loop. Read that pitfalls page for a fun understanding of the different ways bash loops can break your brain.

***Edits**:

- note I didn't run this code, so I'd echo lines and debug as normal (I'm on a tablet).
- Also, I left out your `grep` call because it appeared you are just using it to cat? But if you want to grep, just pass it to `mapfile` as such: `mapfile -t lines < <(grep someExpression "$in_email_file")`
- also `help mapfile` for more

Comment: Thanks, very help info and link.

Comment: @sanodano just curious: did using my solution actually solve your bug/problem?